# C++ {} after method what does it means

Tags: c++11

Hi I have that method

```
surface::surface(const surface& s ) :
    ref{s.ref->clone()}
{}
```

What does {} mean after this method? If possible explain me these on some example.

Comment: This is place where you put your method structure, so something you want this method does.

Comment: But if i dont put anything isnide {} how that will wokr?

Comment: Then your method will do *nothing*.  You have misleading because of `ref{s.ref->clone()}` as this is somesort of extending method. This part is not actual structure of this method

Comment: Remove the colon and the middle line and it might look more familiar to you then

Answer (score 2):

This is not an ordinary method: it's a constructor with an empty body. The key here is what happens after the colon (`:`): these are mem-initializers which tell how to construct the member variables.

Comment: So if I good understand it send us to second constructor which can be in another struct which inherits from this?

Comment: @gamernoob indeed. If ref is not a member, but a base class, it'll tell how to construct the base class. Note that all the mem-initializers are invoked before the body is executed (when the body is not empty as in your example).

Comment: Could you explain me how this will work here https://github.com/supremacey/cpp-hans/blob/master/lab/lab11/code/surface.h